# ArcGIS Length and Area Calculation Scenarios

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

Trying to get a handle on how length and area are calculated in different scenarios in ArcGIS. I don't know why I can't find a answer on the feature class fields, but I can't find a precise answer, unless I'm not understanding something and I know there is some history. Can you help me fill in the question marks? Or tell me why I'm going about this all wrong ; )

GCS = Geographic coordinate system
PCS = Projected coordinate system
All links are to 10.1 help docs --

1. Feature Class shape_length and shape_area fields
   a. GCS - ?
   b. PCS - Using simple planar
   c. Is it always auto-updated, except for shapefiles? yes
2. ArcMap Measurment Tool
   a. GCS - default geodesic, alternatives are Loxodrome and Great Elliptic, but not planar. Area calculation not available!
   b. PCS - default planar, alternatives Geodesic, Loxodrome, and Great Elliptic
   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000022000000
3. Attribute Table Calculator
   a. GCS - not available
   b. PCS - planar
   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000027000000
4. Calculate Field Tool (Data Management toolbox)
   a. GCS - geodesic linear, area available but questionable
   b. PCS - planar
   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000
5. Buffering Tool (and other tools coming)
   a. GCS - geodesic
   b. PCS - planar or specify GCS output
   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000
6. Javascript API Clientside
   a. GCS - geodesic area and length functions
   b. PCS - can convert from web mercator to geographic (or use geometry service)
   http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/namespace_geometry.htm
7. Flex API Clientside
   a. GCS - geodesic area and length functions, "The length [or area] will be calculated using a custom cylindrical equal-area projection". This is not mentioned in the javascript api!!
   b. PCS - can convert from web mercator to geographic 
   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/apiref/com/esri/ags/utils/GeometryUtil.html
8. ArcGIS Server REST API - Geometry Service
   a. GCS - geodesic
   b. PCS - planar
   http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/geometryservice.htm

Another question, what exactly is a geodesic measurement? I thought it meant a 3D trig formula on a spheroid (haversine?). And is it too slow to use in calculating an area and that is why equal area projections are used?

Another question, when determining length and area -- is an equal area projection more accurate than a geodesic calculation using the same datum, spheroid? And briefly why?

Comment: Concerning the last question, please see [What is the most accurate coordinate system for calculating areas of polygons?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20054). For the penultimate, because there exist equal area projections for *ellipsoids,* it is much easier to compute areas with such projections than to write ellipsoid-specific code. The situation is not as nice for computing *distances,* because no projection faithfully reproduces all distances: thus, direct spherical and ellipsoidal distance formulas are often implemented in good GISes.

Comment: 1.b, 3.b and 4.b use the _projected_ coordinate system, so therefore planar.

1.c is always auto-updated when you use a geodatabase (personal/file/SDE).

Comment: Removed some questions marks based on comments. Just found this post with some good info as well (more open source) 
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/711/how-can-i-measure-area-from-geographic-coordinates

Comment: I think it might be best to split your questions. That way you will get the best answers for each one. It would be easier to vote on the answers that way, too.

Comment: I think there are around 10 questions here, each of which would most likely have been quickly answered if they had been presented one at a time (as separate Questions).  Lumping lots of questions in one makes it hard for our Q&A style of responding.

Comment: I agree that it's not a good Q/A-- I flagged it to change to a community wiki, but I think it is helpful to have all the scenarios together.

Comment: This is *not* a good candidate for CW. Moreover, it arguably is not too broad: it only seems so due to its careful enumeration of the many different ways ArcGIS offers to perform area and length calculations. It is still one single question that has been very clearly focused.

Comment: @whuber What is CW? Cutting up, willy-nilly?

Comment: @martin f It's [StackExchange lingo](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=CW).

Answer (score 5):

Your question is essentially one on the accurate (and efficient) calculation of length and area over a large region. The practical details (in this case, concerning ArcGIS) are already being filled in by you and others. They also seem to point to these general conclusions:

- length is best calculated via geodetic (geographic) coordinates
- area is best calculated via equal-area-projection planar coordinates 
  [Edit: But the complexity of the boundary, or the number of vertices
  needed to describe it, is a factor too -- see @cffk's answer]

Here is some explanation:

A *geodesic* is

> the shortest line between two points on a mathematically defined
>   surface (as a straight line on a plane or an arc of a great circle on
>   a sphere)

http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=geodesic%20line
(FYI, on an ellipsoid, a geodesic is generally slightly S-shaped.)

While calculations of geodesics (lengths on an ellipsoid) are relatively difficult, as compared to using the well-known Pythagoras equation, they are possible and accurate. They are relatively easy, however, compared to calculations of *areas* on an ellipsoid.

Map projections don't generally preserve *linear* scales, so projection coordinates aren't generally good for length calculations. (There are exceptions but those depend on where you are on the projection or in what direction you are going.)  As for *area*, there is a class of projections which does preserve *areal* scale exactly: equal-area projections.  Calculating areas on a plane is fairly simple to do, and, if an equal-area projection is used, it is accurate.

There are many good sources on geodesy or map projections that may help. For example, *Geometrical Geodesy: Using Information and Computer Technology* by Maarten Hooijberg.

Comment: Characterizing a geodesic as being S-shaped is probably misleading because it implies that it isn't a shortest path.  I'm aware of various figures that depict the geodesic as an S-shaped curve sandwiched between two normal sections.  But I suspect that these are not accurate.

Comment: If neither of the two normal sections is the geodesic, shouldn't the geodesic be sandwiched between the them and coincide appropriately with each at the ends?

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question about measuring areas.  If you want to measure
the area of a polygon whose edges are geodesics you have two choices:

1. project the polygon to an equal area projection, inserting
   sufficient additional vertices on each edge to ensure that the projected
   edges faithfully follow the geodesic, and measure the area in the
   projected space;
2. use the formulas for the area of a geodesic
   polygon.

The second method is generally faster and more accurate unless the polygon
edges are very short.  Unfortunately arcgis doesn't implement this method (but
it should!).  However [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sf.net/) and [proj](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) (version 4.9.0 and later)
do.  See the
[Wikipedia article on the area of a geodesic polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid#Area_of_a_geodesic_polygon) for more information.

Comment: +1 I worry, however, about the accuracy in the geodesic calculations when applied to small polygons (such as areas of residential parcels): because it is adding and subtracting huge areas to arrive at the final area, there is tremendous cancellation and loss of precision. When coordinates were truly double precision this probably wasn't an issue, but with GISes that discretize their coordinates to an integral grid for their calculations (which includes ArcGIS), this would plausibly wipe out almost all the inherent precision and produce garbage results.

Comment: There's nothing much that can be done if the starting coordinates have errors.  However the overall accuracy of the geodesic area formulas using double precision is at worst 0.1 m^2 per vertex.  Typical errors are much less.  I did a careful check for the boundaries of various provinces in Poland.  E.g., the polygon for Krakow has 8416 vertices (longest edge = 405 m, shortest edge = 0.02 m).  True area (WGS84) = 326798565.428446 m^2, computed area (GeographicLib's Planimeter utility) = 326798565.4285 m^2.

Comment: Right: double precision is fine, because it has about 52 bits of precision and you lose no more than 20 with the Gauss-Bonnet (angular excess) calculations.  But signed integers have at most 32 bits of precision (and often quite a bit less, depending on how the analysis area is initialized), so losing 20 of them might become noticeable.  I'm talking about loss of precision in the calculations, not the effects of errors in the coordinates themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure why I would want to represent any real quantities as signed integers in the middle of a calculation like this.  (Also where does your estimate of 20 digits for the loss of precision come from?)  I do agree that estimating the error for realistic polygons is difficult.  So in the case of Krakow quoted above, I computed the true area by brute force (evaluating the area formulas retaining 20 terms in the series and using 75-digit arithmetic).  I also have similar data for other provinces of Poland and for the whole country (68000 vertices), area = 312e9 m^2, error = 0.001 m^2.

Comment: You don't have any choice if you are using ArcGIS or any other GIS that internally converts all coordinates to an integral grid. The estimate of 20 bits (not decimal digits!) comes from comparing a parcel of, say, a few 10s of meters on a side to the distances typically involved in world-scale areas, which are a few tens of millions: six orders of magnitude is about 6/log(2)=20 bits.

Comment: OK.  However, I still don't see why representing coordinates on an integer grid necessitates doing computations on those coordinates using integers instead of double precision.  So it seems to me that you take a hit on accuracy up front quantizing the coordinates to a grid.  However the additional error due to series truncation and round off during the area calculation can be made quite small (see the examples above).