# Prior art on rhumb line and great ellipse areas?

Tags: area, geodesic, rhumb-line

I'm adding the computation of the area betweeen a rhumb line or a great
ellipse and the equator to [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net).  My formulations are
briefly given in [here](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/1.39/rhumb.html#rhumbarea) and [here](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/1.39/greatellipse.html#gearea).  These formulations are
similar to the one used by GeographicLib in computation geodesic areas.
With these basic areas known, it will be possible to compute the area of
a polygon whose sides are a mixture of geodesics, rhumb lines, or great
ellipses.

Is there any "prior art" I should reference?  I'm particularly
interested in methods which apply to the ellipsoid and can deal with
long segments without slicing the area into many strips.  How do the
commercial tools, ArcGIS and Blue Marble, solve these problems?

Comment: Standard practice would be to do the calcs in an appropriately local equal area projection. Right?  The only real issue is whether your shapes have sensible topology and/or sufficient vertices to represent whatever the thing is correctly when you transform, or draw it in that  projection. (But this a constant concern that is basically a broken part of most/all GIS, and a key knowledge base item  of the "expert-practitioner").

Comment: @mdsumner, you're right that using an equal angle projection is the
standard way to handle area calculations.  However, the need to insert
(a possibly large number of) intermediate vertices makes this method
equivalent to "slicing the area into many strips".  As a result, the
calculation either slow or inaccurate or both.  I'm interested in
methods which don't have this limitation.

Comment: Equal area not angle. The extra vertices are not for calculating per se, just for representing the region in the right way. I don't get your overall task really, I don't see how it's any different to calculating area normally.

Comment: Consider measuring the area of an polygon where one side is a rhumb line
running SE from 39N 120W to 35N 115.0107164W (part of the border between
California and Nevada).  This "line" becomes a curve in the Lambert
equal-area cylindrical projection (and most other equal area
projections).  So you'll need to insert intermediate points on rhumb
line to be able to represent the polygon accurately in an equal-area
projection.  So instead of doing one unit of work to calculate the area
contribution of this edge, you'll have to do 630 units of work (assuming
you need to insert one point per km).

Comment: Ok thanks, we are on the same page at least. I don't see a problem with this, it's a limitation in most systems that the "curve" must be stored as an approximation rather than be generated on the fly from a rhumb or gc rule. I am interested to see if there will be any answers.

Comment: Danielsen http://dx.doi.org/10.1179/003962689791474267 solved the
problem where the edge is a geodesic in 1989 and that solution is
employed by GeographicLib.  Extending the technique to rhumb lines and
great ellipses is straightforward enough (see the links in the
question).

Comment: Somewhat related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41157/arcgis-length-and-area-calculation-scenarios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the result I derived for the rhumb line area.  This is the more
interesting result.  The great ellipse formula is more complex and is
very similar to that for geodesics.

Consider a rhumb line from (φ<sub>1</sub>,λ<sub>1</sub>) to
(φ<sub>2</sub>,λ<sub>2</sub>).  Determine the area of the
ellipsoidal quadrilateral whose sides are this rhumb line segment, two
meridional segments, and a segment of equator (the "area under the rhumb
line").  Once we have this area, we can easily determine the area of any
polygon with rhumb line edges, by summing over the edges.

The derivation of the area is outlined in the
[link given in the question](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/1.39/rhumb.html#rhumbarea).

The area can by expressed as

*S*<sub>12</sub> = *c*<sup>2</sup> (λ<sub>2</sub> − λ<sub>1</sub>)
[(*S*(χ<sub>2</sub>) − *S*(χ<sub>1</sub>)) /
(ψ<sub>2</sub> − ψ<sub>2</sub>)],

where *c* is the authalic radius, χ is the conformal latitude,
ψ is the isometric latitude,

*S*(χ) = log sec χ +
∑<sub>*k* = 1</sub> *R*<sub>*k*</sub> cos(2*k*χ)

and *R*<sub>*k*</sub> = *O*(*n*<sup>*k*</sup>)
are series in the third flattening *n* which can be found using
[Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net).

Points to note:

- In the spherical limit, the sum vanishes, leaving a rather simple
  result.  This *must* have been found already.  Can someone point me
  to a reference?
- The area can be expressed as a product of the longitude difference
  and an expression that depends on the latitudes of the endpoints
  only.
- In the limit φ<sub>2</sub> → φ<sub>1</sub>, the
  term in square brackets reduces to sin ξ<sub>1</sub> where ξ is
  the authalic latitude.
- When evaluating the term in square brackets, [divided differences](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/1.39/rhumb.html#divideddiffs)
  should be used to avoid any loss of accuracy due to the subtraction.
- When evaluating the sum, use [Clenshaw summation](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/1.39/rhumb.html#dividedclenshaw) to avoid
  multiple calls to the cosine function.
- I estimate that only the first six terms in the sum need to be
  included to obtain a result that is accurate to round-off for
  terrestrial ellipsoids.

**ADDENDUM:** My on-line planimeter utility

http://geographiclib.sf.net/cgi-bin/Planimeter

now supports the computation of polygons whose edges are rhumb lines
(select the "Rhumb line" radio button).  For example, to compute the
area of Wyoming, enter the coordinates

```
41N 111:3W
41N 104:3W
45N 104:3W
45N 111:3W
```

Similarly to compute the area of the arctic circle, enter the
coordinates

```
66:33:44 0
66:33:44 180
```

(This works because the utility picks the east-going rhumb line when the
vertices are on opposite meridians.)

Please let me know if you discover any problems with this utility.

**ADDENDUM 2:**

8 years later, I've gotten around to writing up this work in [The area of rhumb polygons](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.03219).